# me aparecio este error en mi interfaz grafica, relacionada a "local variable" algun consejo?

Tags: python, tkinter, numpy

*funcion*

```
def sacar_promedio():
    total=[]
    tra=ventas[semana.get()-1,trabajador.get()-1]
    total.append(tra)
    if semana.get() ==  1:
        total1 = ((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))
        total2 = ((((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))/7))
        
    elif semana.get() == 2:
        total1 = ((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))
        total2 = ((((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))/7))
    elif semana.get() == 3:
        total1 = ((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))
        total2 = ((((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))/7))
    elif semana.get() == 4:
        total1 = ((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))
        total2 = ((((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))/7))
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Semana incorrecta, introduzca nuevamente")
    mensaje.set("El promedio semanal del trabajador es: "+str(round(total2)))**aqui me tira error**
    mensaje2.set("El Total semanal del trabajor es: "+str(round(total1)))**aqui igual**
    ventana.withdraw()
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.geometry('380x300')
    win.config(bg="dark turquoise")
    e5 = tk.Label(win, text="Resultado final")
    e5.pack(side=tk.TOP)
    etiqueta2 = Label(win, textvariable=mensaje).place(x=100, y=150)
    etiqueta3 = Label(win, textvariable=mensaje2).place(x=100, y=200)**texto en negrita**
```

me sale que tengo un error de local variable 'total2'referenced before assigment, probe poniendo global en la otra funcion que llamo pero aun asi me sigue tirando error :c

Comment: Bueno, si todos tus demas condicionales fallan, se ejecuta el else. Alli no estas inicializando la variable total2 en ningun momento. Luego, Python se queja de que la variable aun no fue creada.

Comment: Puede ser lo que dice dante, o que tengas una variable global llamada `total2`, en cuyo caso debes poner al inicio de la función que muestras la declaración `global total2`

Comment: lo intente y aun asi me sigue fallando, les paso el codigo entero?

Comment: No dentro de lo posible, te recomiendo crear un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y publicarlo. De esa manera sabremos facilmente que esta saliendo mal con el menor código posible.

Comment: ya me funciono, pero ahora el problema esque solo me toma un valor para todas las semanas y trabajadores :c